# Overflow: hidden not working for transform: rotate

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

Please kindly visit the following web page to see, what the problem is (a plunkr or something would be too complex for this layout, so sorry for external link) [*LINK IS DEAD*]

You should see a full-screen picture of a dancing girl. When you scroll down, the girl is supposed to rotate. The girl is a div called with class `.girl`. It's parent, `.big-pic-panel.dance` is obviously set to have `overflow: hidden` but as you see the picture is covering the text below. So, obviously, the `overflow` property is being ignored.

Have I missed something or is it a bug?

The **second** problem is, in IE the picture is differently positioned than in Chrome... Hints about this?

Comment: You are using absolute position so the parents img is no longer the container add position:relative to the big-pic-panel.dance and will work

Comment: Awesome. It worked. If you post it as answer, I will be happy to accept and +1 it.